# Dictionary sorting based on the Value of lists in the value

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
my_dict = {'name':['a','b','c','d','e'],'c1':[0,0,1,2,0],'c2':[3,0,2,1,2],'c3':[1,2,3,4,5]}
```

I want to sort the dictionary based on the value of `c1` and `c2`. How can I do that?
I.e. Priority to sort the dict is using C1 but if C1 has to same values like c1[0] and c1[1] at that time it short the data based on C2 data.

I have tried below but getting error:

```
c1_list = count_dict.get('c1')
c1_list.sort(reverse=True)

index_map = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(c1_list)}
print sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda pair: index_map[pair[0]])
```

Expected Output:

```
{'name':['d','c','a','e','b'],'c1':[2,1,0,0,0],'c2':[1,2,3,2,0],'c3':[4,3,1,5,2]}
```

Comment: This is not giving expected results. I have to sort the dictionary based on the value of a list. not the key

Comment: Can someone explain to me how values of `name` and `c3` are sorted in order like that if it's based on both `c1` and `c2`?

Comment: What do you mean by "sort by value of `c1` __and__ `c2`? What does the __and__ mean in that context? The sum of both values? And you do not want to sort the dictionary, you apparently want to sort the values of the keys according to the unknown rule.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa C1 and C2 means first we need to sort using C1 but if C1 has 2 same values then in that case for those similar values it should use C2 for sorting

Comment: Your toy example works if I take the sum of the values of `c1` and `c2`. I do not understand the rule "if C1 has 2 same values" if you want to sort your values elementwise.

Comment: Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54362407/dictionary-sorting-based-on-a-list-in-the-value/54363906#54363906) for sorting based on the order `c1, c2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Pandas

Normally I'd use `numpy` for this, but since it does not have a convenient constructor for conversion of dictionaries to structured arrays, I recommend to use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {'name':['a','b','c','d','e'],'c1':[0,0,1,2,0],'c2':[3,0,2,1,2],'c3':[1,2,3,4,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['c1', 'c2'])[::-1]
sorted_dict = df_sorted.to_dict('list')
```

Output:

```
 {'name': ['d', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'b'], 'c1': [2, 1, 0, 0, 0], 'c2': [1, 2, 3, 2, 0], 'c3': [4, 3, 1, 5, 2]}
```

Comment: This solution works only for the given data. Even if i add a single new element it is giving wrong result: my_dict = {'name':['a','b','c','d','e'],'c1':[0,0,1,2,0],'c2':[3,0,2,1,2],'c3':[1,2,3,4,5]}   O/P: {'c3': [4, 3, 1, 5, 2], 'c2': [1, 2, 2, 3, 0], 'c1': [2, 1, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['d', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'b']}

Comment: Which of both solutions?

Comment: Both the solutions. I have updated the Description.

Comment: The pure python solution does not solve the updated OP, I removed it. The pandas solution solves it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort all values in specific reversed order, here values of `c2` and `c1`, you could [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) them together and use `key` parameter of [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to sort all values in saved order.

**Python 3**

```
my_dict = my_dict = {'name':['a','b','c','d','e'],'c1':[0,0,1,2,0],'c2':[3,0,2,1,2],'c3':[1,2,3,4,5]}
sort_by = [my_dict['c1'], my_dict['c2']]

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    my_dict[k] = [i for *_, i in sorted(zip(*sort_by, v), key=lambda x: x[:-1], reverse=True)]

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'name': ['d', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'b'], 'c1': [2, 1, 0, 0, 0], 'c2': [1, 2, 3, 2, 0], 'c3': [4, 3, 1, 5, 2]}
```

---

**Python 2**

```
my_dict = my_dict = {'name':['a','b','c','d','e'],'c1':[0,0,1,2,0],'c2':[3,0,2,1,2],'c3':[1,2,3,4,5]}
sort_by = [my_dict['c1'], my_dict['c2']]

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    my_dict[k] = [i[0] for i in sorted(zip(v, *sort_by), key=lambda x: x[1:], reverse=True)]

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'name': ['d', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'b'], 'c1': [2, 1, 0, 0, 0], 'c2': [1, 2, 3, 2, 0], 'c3': [4, 3, 1, 5, 2]}
```

Comment: Still c2 comes first, not working.

Comment: What do you mean? Output is what OP desired.

Comment: Still it is sorting only based on C2: my_dict = {'name':['a','b','c','d'],'c1':[0,0,1,2],'c2':[3,0,2,1],'c3':[1,2,3,4]}
sort_by = my_dict['c2']
for k in my_dict:
    my_dict[k] = sorted(my_dict[k], key=lambda x: sort_by[my_dict[k].index(x)], reverse=True)

print(my_dict)       Output: {'c3': [1, 3, 4, 2], 'c2': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'c1': [0, 0, 1, 2], 'name': ['a', 'c', 'd', 'b']}

Comment: Updated my answer for sorting with multiple keys `c2` and `c1`

Comment: Still not giving the correct output

Comment: Output is exactly the same as one you claimed to be right in the question.

Comment: This solution works only for the given data. Even if i add a single new element it is giving wrong result: my_dict = {'name':['a','b','c','d','e'],'c1':[0,0,1,2,0],'c2':[3,0,2,1,2],'c3':[1,2,3,4,5]} O/P: {'c3': [4, 3, 1, 5, 2], 'c2': [1, 2, 2, 3, 0], 'c1': [2, 1, 0, 0, 0], 'name': ['d', 'c', 'a', 'e', 'b']}

Comment: Add that example and output you're expecting to the question, its unreadable this way.

Comment: I have updated the Description with output.

Comment: Updated my answer to sort it primarily by `c1` and secondly by `c2`, try it now.

Comment: Thanks..!! But can you update the description this works only with python > 3.5

Comment: Yes, I also added code that works in python 2.*. Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :)